# Cocoa - Custom appearance of NSStatusItem in menu bar

Tags: cocoa, nsstatusitem

It is easy to set the title and length of an NSStatusItem. Is is possible to change the appearance of the NSStatusItem entirely, and replace it with a custom view?

For example, if I want my NSStatusItem to be a whole row of icons surrounded by a border, rather than just a single icon, and each icon can be separately clicked. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. I can use NSStatusItem's `setView:` method to completely customize the appearance of the NSStatusItem.

An example of this is [here](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem).