# how do I use a custom NSView in the menu bar loaded from a nib

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

First, new to Cocoa and Objective-C, so my apologies if this is unclear and I misuse all the terminology, gentle corrections are appreciated.

I'm trying to write a very simple app that has something chilling in the menu bar.

I've gotten pretty close, I can get a basic text menu up there, but I would really like
to have a custom view in the actual menu part, like this:
[image: screenshot of where i want the custom view]

I got really hopeful when I found [the example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952412/cocoa-custom-appearance-of-nsstatusitem-in-menu-bar), and I can kind of see where he's sending `setView` to his `statusItem` with his own view object, but I would like to design my view in Interface Builder.

I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491541/load-xib-files-with-nsview) that I can get to set an instance variable to my initialized custom designed view object (probably in a really awful way), but when I try to then send that variable to `setView` nothing show's up.

I've read a lot about `drawRect`, and I'm guessing that it has something to do with what the answer will be, but my Cocoa chops aren't there yet.

can someone paint a complete picture of all these steps? I feel like I have a lot of the puzzle pieces but I've lost the lid.

Comment: I also bet I'm not setting the frame right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use drawRect (unless you're doing your own custom drawing) or set the frame, you can do it in IB.  Just drag out a custom view, size it appropriately, and put whatever you want into it.  Have an IBOutlet in one of your classes that connects to it, and after creating your status bar item call setView: on it with your IBOutlet to the custom view as the argument.  The status bar is only 22 pixels high, so your view needs to take that into account.  There seems to be some strange behavior of this status item, with respect to the struts in the autosizing feature in IB.  I've noticed that if either the top strut or right strut is on by itself, the view doesn't appear ( but left or bottom are ok).  It also seems to work with all 4 either on or off.